# Renaming of Label issue in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label

This is my code for renaming the Label:

```
If cb1.SelectedIndex = 0
    lbl1.text = "BPO No:"
ElseIf cb1.SelectedIndex = 1
    lbl1.text = "Purchase Order No:"
End If
```

If I choose 0, then this is the output:

[image]

If I choose 1, then this is the output:

[image]

Now what I want is this:

[image]

I already think of the solution for this by changing the position of the label, but is it okay or is there other solution for this?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `lbl1` a specified width, big enough to hold the largest text you will put in it, then set the `TextAlign` property of the label to `MiddleRight` in code-behind, like this:

```
lbl1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight
```

OR set the `TextAlign` property in the designer.

Comment: Thank you! this is excatly what I am looking for, big help :)